# help with displaying a variable in jade express

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm trying to load some variables with res render like that:

```
res.render('blog_edit', {title: 'edit your blog', posts: "something"});
```

though title loads fine post always appears as undefined...
here are some of the ways I tried...

```
=posts

#{posts}
```

and  as a javascript variable

```
script   
   document.write(posts)
```

none of them is working... can you please help?
thanks in advance

Comment: `#{posts}` works under express 3.x

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try

```
  res.render('blog_edit', {locals:{title: 'edit your blog', posts: "something"}});

        #{locals.foo}
```

Comment: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade if you look under the section public api it tells you the ways you can pass in variables(not very clearly though) Using locals is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: If I had to pass the same thing to an ejs file it gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using the latest versions today ("express": "4.11.2", "jade": "1.9.2") and this is the syntax that works for me:

```
res.render('blog_edit', {title: 'edit your blog', posts: "something"});
```

In template:

```
#{locals.posts}
```

or

```
#{posts}
```

Comment: Express 4.13 jade 1.11 but both ways don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me.

```
in JS
    res.render('index',  {email: req.params.email});

in Jade
   #{locals.email}
```