# Express & jade (node.js) - variable is not defined error when checking for existence

Tags: javascript, node.js, view, pug

I'm getting a pretty dumb error on a extremely simple express app. I am using jade as the view engine, I'm saying this just in case it is related to the problem.

I'm trying to check if a variable is defined in order to render one thing or another, but simply checking for that variable triggers a "variable is not defined" Error. This is not the behaviour I'd expect, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. This is the view code I'm using:

```
h1= title
- if (user)
    p Welcome to #{title}, #{user.username}
- else 
    p Welcome to #{title}
```

What is the right way to do this? There must be a way to check for variables on the views. :-/

EDIT: Forgot to say on what line the error is triggered, it is triggered on the second line "- if (user)".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As is mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7161128/262789) the [Public API](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#public-api) section of the Jade documentation says that the `locals` variable is how data is passed to a Jade template. On a lark I prepended my variables in the jade template with `locals`. This correctly bypassed the error.

So the following Jade template should resolve your error:

```
h1= title
- if (locals.user)
    p Welcome to #{title}, #{user.username}
- else 
    p Welcome to #{title}
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You didn't enclose `p Welcome to #{title}; #{user.username}` in quotes</strike>

try

```
if(typeof obj != 'undefined')
```

Comment: This does work, thanks!. I still think the simple check should work though, it is much cleaner :-(.

Answer (score 1):

layout.jade

```
# the following function is a safe getter/setter for locals
- function pagevar(key, value) { var undef; return (value===undef) ? locals[key] || null : locals[key] = value; }
block config
  #intended as a non-rendered block so that locals can be overridden.
  # put your defaults here... - use append in the child view
!!!
html
  head
    title=pagevar('title')
    meta(name='description',content=pagevar('description'))
...
```

page.jade

```
append config
  - locals.title = 'override';
  - locals.description = 'override 2';
  - pagevars('somekey', 'some value');
...
```

Easy peazy.