# Passing a variable from node.js to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to pass a variable from node.js to my HTML file.

```
app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
  var name = 'hello';
  res.render(__dirname + "/views/layouts/main.html", {name:name});
});
```

Comment: HTML is not a templating language, it can't be sent variables.

Comment: Maybe you could load the HTML and run it through some regexes, but it won't be clean.

Comment: <a id="WhatIAmLookingFor"><\a> in html, and with jquerry: $("#WhatIAmLookingFor").text('name')

Comment: @JanDvorak i am then using the variable to send it to a javascript file

Comment: @Destrif that's not the question, even remotely so, and why do you even think the asker uses jQuery?

Comment: @vic-3 I can't see any client-side javascript file here, just an inline tag. Those can't be sent variables either, though they can access the global scope. They can be generated to set a javascript variable, but you aren't doing that either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328028/node-js-passing-parameters-to-client-via-express-render

Comment: You are sending a script tag with some templating tags inside, but the server has no idea it should be modifying them, or how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variables between Node.js Server and Client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955697/variables-between-node-js-server-and-client)

Comment: @Destrif I  have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328028/node-js-passing-parameters-to-client-via-express-render before didn't get it to work it just logs {{name}}

Comment: @vic-3 It's because you need a templating engine like handlebars. Are you using one? Or are you using static HTML files?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am just using static Html but i am able to pass a .json but not simple text.

Comment: You really need a templating engine like, jade, pug or even handlebars. Another other approach will be more effort (imo)

Comment: using node you can write your own templating engine, and it's not that difficult. you'd basically do a search and replace before you output the html to the response. teamtreehouse has a nice tutorial you can watch during a free trial.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I figured it out I was able to pass a variable like this

```
<script>var name = "<%= name %>";</script>
console.log(name);
```

Comment: What render engine did you use?

Comment: @AstemirAlmov He is most surely not using HTML, he must be using EJS. Have a look here: http://ejs.co/ . This is what we use with nodejs.

Comment: How to use same thing with html rendered page not with ejs ??

Comment: this uses an engine, and you do not specify the engine you're using

Comment: How could this work with an object instead of an String?

Comment: @vic-3 Do you know if there's a way yo this thing using hbs instead of ejs?

Answer (score 18):

I found the possible way to write.

Server Side -

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/main', function(req, res) {

  var name = 'hello';

  res.render(__dirname + "/views/layouts/main.html", {name:name});

});
```

Client side (main.html) -

```
<h1><%= name %></h1>
```

Comment: What is the view engine you're using here?

Comment: app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

Answer (score 16):

What you can utilize is some sort of templating engine like pug (formerly jade). To enable it you should do the following:

1. `npm install --save pug` - to add it to the project and package.json file
2. `app.set('view engine', 'pug');` - register it as a view engine in express
3. create a `./views` folder and add a simple `.pug` file like so:

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

note that the spacing is very important!

4. create a route that returns the processed html:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});
```

This will render an index.html page with the variables passed in node.js changed to the values you have provided. This has been taken directly from the expressjs templating engine page: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

For more info on pug you can also check: https://github.com/pugjs/pug

Comment: Sorry, I know it completely unrelated to this, but I'm having a problem when passing a variable to my view, and it is really weird. The templates renders perfectly fine, but then in the console (and randomly, there isnt a clear pattern), sometimes throws the error of `can not read property X of undefined` ... but, at the same time the UI renders exactly as it should. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Do you have any javascript on the page? If you do, check who/what is trying to access a field named "X". It should be something along the lines of `something.X`

Comment: I figured out. Never saw this before, but it only happened when dev tools was opened, so then I realised that the server was throwing a 500 error because dev tools was trying to access jquery.min.map (which I didnt have in the vendor folder), so the 500 error was interrupting express and therefore the variables were not passing.

Answer (score 11):

To pass variables from node.js to html by using the res.render() method.

Example:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extend:true}));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html',{email:data.email,password:data.password});
});
```

Comment: this uses ejs view engine

Answer (score 5):

With Node and HTML alone you won't be able to achieve what you intend to; it's not like using PHP, where you could do something like `<title> <?php echo $custom_title; ?>`, without any other stuff installed.

To do what you want using Node, you can either use something that's called a 'templating' engine (like Jade, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160767/help-with-displaying-a-variable-in-jade-express) out) or use some HTTP requests in Javascript to get your data from the server and use it to replace parts of the HTML with it.

Both require some extra work; it's not as *plug'n'play* as PHP when it comes to doing stuff like you want.

Comment: i think it's wrong answier 
in nodejs you can use   <%=   %> 

alert('<%= myVar %>');

Comment: @Bahgat Mashaly  then you do not mind posting an example and showing the rest of the world how that works ? Because the thing you just copy pasted is not native nodeJS. seems like a template engine module that you installed on top of nodeJS.

Answer (score 3):

use res.json, ajax, and promises, with a nice twist of localStorage to use it anywhere, added with tokens for that rare arcade love.  PS, you could use cookies, but cookies can bite on https.

webpage.js

```
function (idToken) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/main',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + idToken
        },
        processData: false,
    }).done(function (data) {
        localStorage.setItem('name', data.name);
        //or whatever you want done.
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        var msg = 'Unable to fetch protected resource';
        msg += '<br>' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText;
        if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
            msg += '<br>Your token may be expired'
        }
        displayError(msg);
    });
```

server.js, using express()

```
app.get('/main',
passport.authenticate('oauth2-jwt-bearer', { session: false }),
function (req, res) {
    getUserInfo(req) //get your information to use it.
        .then(function (userinfo) {  //return your promise
            res.json({ "name": userinfo.Name});
            //you can declare/return more vars in this res.json.
            //res.cookie('name', name); //https trouble
        })
    .error(function (e) {console.log("Error handler " + e)})
    .catch(function (e) {console.log("Catch handler " + e)});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this by a `http API node` request which returns required object from node object for `HTML` page at client ,

for eg: `API: localhost:3000/username`

returns logged in user from cache by node App object .

node route file,

```
app.get('/username', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ udata: req.session.user });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Express it's not necessary to use a View Engine at all, use something like this:

```
<h1>{{ name }} </h1>
```

This works if you previously set your application to use HTML instead of any View Engine

Comment: How can i use list object and looping in html page using this ?

Comment: How does this work in complete code? I'm getting an `Unexpected token <` error.

Comment: this answer is wrong. The {{ }} indicates that some form of templating engine is used, most likely handlebars.

Comment: this answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Other than those on the top, you can use JavaScript to fetch the details from the server. 
html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="test">
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let url="http://localhost:8001/test";
        fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
        .then( (result) => {
            console.log('success:', result)
            let div=document.getElementById('test');
            div.innerHTML=`title: ${result.title}<br/>message: ${result.message}`;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    //res.sendFile(__dirname +"/views/test.html",);
    res.json({title:"api",message:"root"});
})

app.get('/render',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname +"/views/test.html");
})
```

The best answer i found on the stack-overflow on the said subject, it's not my answer. Found it somewhere for nearly same question...source
[source of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141364/how-to-send-some-context-from-node-server-to-html-template-without-using-any-tem)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using cookies, it may help you if you don't want to pass any sensitive values to the client, and only using VanillaJS and Node.js with Express.
I set the values as cookies using the cookie method of res object in my request function:

```
app.post('/app/login',(req, res) { // (POST, '/app/login')   
    const user = req.body.user;
    sessions.push({ sessionId, user});
    res.cookie('user', user);
    res.sendFile('inicio.html');
});
```

It's important to see that I sent an HTML file to the client, later, in the JavaScript file linked to this, I created this function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=> {
    const username = document.cookie.slice(5);
    document.querySelector("#user_h3").innerHTML += username;
});
```

The selector "#user_h3", refers an h3 tag that can chage its content by the innerHTML property using QuerySelector. The HTML looks like this:

```
<h3 id="user_h3" >Welcome, user: </h3>
```