# Give value from node.js to its server's html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I need to give var into my html like server -> client
I'm not good at english and this situation is hard to explain so i will show you the code
html (index.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(tmp) //lol!
</script>
```

node.js:

```
fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
                response.statusCode = 404;
                response.end(`error!`);
        } 
        else
        {
            tmp="lol!"
            response.write(html);
            response.end(); 
        }
    });
```

server should response and give value to client same time. but it didn't work.
i don't want use external modules like express.js or ajax anything need to download things as it's possible
could you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a variable from node.js to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html)

Comment: @Dennington-bear there is no way to send var(or json anything) without using express module like thing? they said they used ejs or express

Comment: @Yosika you can send whatever you like in your response, that's just one methodology. And... "server should response and give value to client same time. " Responding, and giving a value to the client, are the same thing. The response is what you send to the client (as a _response_ to the client's _request_, do you see?). Your code sends some HTML to the client. It also sets a variable called "tmp", which you then don't use for anything. It's not clear what you were expecting to happen. The only thing the client sees is what goes into the response. Everything else is server-side logic,

Comment: @ADyson well you were right, it just methodology problem. I solved this problem by writing div tag <div id="someId" data-config='{"userId": 1234}'></div> to response, and receive var userId = $('#someId').data('config').userId; like this

Comment: yes that's a reasonable approach. Or you could write `var userId = 1234;` directly, if that code is supposed to run immediately after the page loads. The server controls the whole response output, so it can also control what the Javascript in the page is going to contain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
        } 
        else
        {
            var tmp = new Object();
            tmp.string = "hello world!"
            var go = JSON.stringify(tmp)
            res.write(`<div id="data"><div id="list" data-list='${go}'></div></div>`);
            res.write(html);
            res.end(); 
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("list").getAttribute("data-list"));
alert(data.string);
```

make a div element and set attribute, then write in response.