# ExpressJS: call a variable from .js file to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, express, variables, get

I am using express@4.16.2

I want to call a variable from `main.js` to `index.html`

main.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var router = express.Router()
app.use('/',express.static('public'));

app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
    res.send("index", {name:'hello'});
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on 3000'));
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is giving the following result on the webpage:

```
{{ name }}
```

Is there an http get method call that I need to make? What am I missing in between? Any help/hint/guidance would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Try using: `<%= name %>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a variable from node.js to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html)

Comment: <%= name %> gives the output as : <%= name %>

Comment: You are missing a plugin to perform template operations, you need to either write the code yourself or use a library like [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [use a template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) that let you replace variables in the view file with actual values, and transform the template into an HTML file sent to the client.

There are many view engines work in combination with express, you could choose one of them here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

I suggest you to use [ejs](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) since it's very easy to understand, Here is an example using it:

**main.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var router = express.Router()
app.use('/',express.static('public'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
    res.send("index", {name:'hello'});
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on 3000'));
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
<!-- show name -->
<<h1><%= name %></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using hbs syntax:

```
<<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
```

without ever loading the hbs view engine to render it.

example for hbs:

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get("/main", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.hbs", {
        name: "hello"
    });
});

app.listen(<port>);
```

Comment: This gives me the idea of view engine that I have been missing. However, the output I get from the run is: {{ name }}

Comment: as long as you are getting the output {{ name }} that simply means that nothing (i.e view engine) is actually picking up on it to replace it.

Have you npm install hbs (or any other view-engine for that matter, i simply only am familiar with hbs personally but there a lot of others)?

Have you initiated it properly?

Is your file structure matching hbs requirements, have you configured the proper settings?

Are you sending the app.get with the proper syntax and details?