# nodejs read config file in html file

Tags: html, node.js, express, configuration

I have a config file where I have kept all the configuration.

```
app: {
   root: 'rooturl'
}
```

I have a html file that is basically a template.

Now I want to read that config file in html

```
<img src='rooturl'>
```

How can I read root from config in html file

I tried googling but didn't find anything

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: do you use express.js?

Comment: Yes I use express, I tried using require, but dont know how to give the src

Comment: Which template engine you are using in your project?

Comment: No template engine, its an api codebase, I need to send html file to email

Comment: maybe you should use a template engine please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html if you don't use template engine maybe you should first read html file contents and then replace string.

Comment: `htmlcontents= htmlcontents.replace('rooturl', app.root)`

Comment: replace I am using. but being a fresher for node.js I am curious to know is there anything like inline replacement

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement it this way, makes three files as shown below and run it. I have used little jQuery which will be very usefull in DOM manipulation.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="add.js"></script>
     </head>
        <body>

         <img alt="Pulpit Rock" width="284" height="213"><br>

         <button>Set the width attribute of the image</button>

       </body>
    </html>
```

In following file I have used jQuery for setting the src attribute of `<img>`.

add.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

        $("img").attr("src", app.root);

    });
});
```

config.js

```
app = { 
    root: "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/img_pulpitrock.jpg" 
}
```