# pass value from node.js to javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to work with Google's example code: [PhotoFrame](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-photos).
It is built with node.js, expressjs, jQuery, etc.
I need to pass a variable -- let's call it myString -- from app.js to one of the .js files -- let's call it myScript.js.
I've tried at least a dozen approaches that I found at StackOverflow and elsewhere. None has worked.

Some folks have said "just use a global, even though they're 'BAD'.
In app.js you:

```
global.myStringGlobal = myString
```

and in myScript you:

```
var myStringLocal = myStringGlobal;
```

Doesn't work: myStringGlobal is undefined.

Some folks say: code a little object in app.js and module.export it.
Them require it in myScript. Doesn't work: require is undefined in myScript.
In fact, since myScript and myOtherScripts run in the browser, require
is simply un-available.

Some folks say code this in app.js:

`res.render(page, {myString: myString});`

Others say "No, that sends myString to the html renderer; not to myString.
They're correct.

I won't drag this out by telling you the other ways I tried in vain.

This question has been asked and answered many times in various ways,
but none of the answers work -- anymore? or who knows why?

So I ask again: does anyone know how to pass a variable from the node.js
app.js script to some myScript.js file?

Comment: As an alternative, maybe you can pass it via ajax.

Comment: This question title is like "pass value from clang to c++". Or maybe "pass value from Rails to Ruby".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explanation.

You have to know that you have been involved into different app. Your `express` app is a server side app, while another would be client side app. So, the main question is, how to pass data from server to client?

If you're thinking about `ajax`, then you're right. I'm not using `jQuery` anymore, but I think you can use something like `$.get(..)`.

**server**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

// Data can be requested via GET method
app.get('/sample-api', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ text: 'Lorem Ipsum' });
});

// You can render page here...

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
```

**client**

```
$(function() {
    var msgFromServer;
    $.get( "/sample-api", function( data ) {
        msgFromServer = data.text;
        alert( "Received data from server!" );
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes. You are indeed passing from server-side to client-side. Can you be more specific about how to code the ajax?

Answer (score 1):

From Expressjs, you can pass a variable along with a page [when you render it](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render). In the render call, you name the view you're trying to render and you can pass variables along with it:

```
app.render('email', { name: 'Tobi' }, function(err, html){
  // ...
});
```

This passes a variable named 'name' to the email view with the value 'Tobi'. You can then use the variable in the HTML

```
<script>var name = "<%= name %>";</script>
```

See [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html)

Comment: This approach hasn't worked for me. The  app.js code: 'res.render(page, {authTok: authTok});'. The album.ejs code:'<script>authorizeToken =  "<%= name %>";</script>'. The album.js code: 'var tok = authorizeToken' yields undefined.

Comment: The variable being set in the render is authTok. You need to use that variable name in the <%= %>