# How to implement token based authentication in oauth2.0 process

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth

Below is my understanding of the process of oauth2.0(using google as the oauth2.0 server)

1. my customer click 'login with google account' button on client side.
2. the browser redirect to google's login page.
3. my customer inputs it's credential and click 'login'.
4. if my customer succeeded in previous step,the browser will redirect to my server's url
   (www.[myserver].com/auth/google/callback) with some extra query
   data.
5. then my server will do some work to get some token from google and finally get my customer's information.

My question comes from the next step. I want to use token based authentication.Then I have to make my customer to store my own token in localStorage. I can't figure out how to achieve this in the 6th step(how to send a new token to client side and store it in localStorage?).
(I know that every thing will be easy if I am using cookie-based authentication. because I can just utilize 'set-cookie' in the 6th step, and the client side will be easily store the credential data in client side's cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Google APIs use the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication and authorization. Google supports common OAuth 2.0 scenarios such as those for web server, installed, and client-side applications.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that I can use some type of template engine on my server side([just like discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html)). So I can render my template file using variable before send it to my customer.