# How to send scraped data to index html file to load

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am new to node.js and Puppeteer and may not be asking this correctly. I was able to create a web scraper to grab data. What I am wanting to do is send this information I received and push it to a HTML file to load locally on my machine to show the results instead of having it inside my console.

Is there anyway to do this?
Do I need to use another framework?

Any useful tips or resources would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a variable from node.js to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html)

Answer (score 1):

To create a HTML file, you can use your variables and [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) to generate a HTML file with your content.

**Example:**

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// ... crawling is done, variable are filled
const result1 = 'Some data';
const result2 = 'More crawled data';

const resultHtml = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head><title>Crawling results</title></head>
<body>
<p>Result 1: ${result1}</p>
<p>Result 2: ${result2}</p>
<p>...</p>
</body>
</html>`;

fs.writeFileSync('results.html', resultHtml);
```

You can then open the `results.html` file locally in your browser to view the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a templating language like [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) to render the data to an HTML template and write the result to an HTML file.