# How to display a variable in html generated with node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

For training purposes, I am trying to display a portion of the pathname in my html page.

For instance, if URL is like : http://localhost:8080/firstname/abcd

I expect my browser to display: *"Hello abcd"*

```
const config = require('./config');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url'); 

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    if(path.includes('firstname'))
    {
        firstname = path.replace('/firstname/', '');

        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.write('<!DOCTYPE html>'+
            '<html>'+
            '    <head>'+
            '        <meta charset="utf-8" />'+
            '        <title>Node.js tests</title>'+
            '    </head>'+ 
            '    <body>'+
            '       <p id = "name"></p>'+
            '    </body>'+
            '<script type="text/javascript">
            'document.getElementsById("name").innerHTML = ("Hello " + firstname)'+
            '</script>'+
            '</html>');
        res.end();
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Nothing to display');
    }
});
server.listen(config.env.port);
```

As you can guess, the page appears empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a variable from node.js to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html)

Comment: "document.getElementsById" this is wrong it should be "document.getElementById", that is 's' should not be there.

Comment: You're right uday214125. I've been testing with getElementsByTagName before this is why. But weird, ElementsById seems to be working too. Anyway, I'll fix this too, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just display the path except the `firstname` part, then:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    if(path.includes('firstname'))
    {
        let firstname = path.replace('/firstname/', '');
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.write('<!DOCTYPE html>'+
        '<html>'+
        '    <head>'+
        '        <meta charset="utf-8" />'+
        '        <title>Node.js tests</title>'+
        '    </head>'+ 
        '    <body>'+
        '       <p id = "name">'+
              'hello ' + firstname +
              '</p>'+
        '    </body>'+            
        '</html>');
    }
    else
    {        
        res.write('Nothing to display');
    }
    res.end();
});
server.listen(config.env.port);
```

Going to `http://localhost:8080/firstname/abcd` gives `Hello abcd`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use js code in HTML?

You can render a static HTML page and send it as a response.
Like this:

```
...
        res.write('<!DOCTYPE html>'+
            '<html>'+
            '    <head>'+
            '        <meta charset="utf-8" />'+
            '        <title>Node.js tests</title>'+
            '    </head>'+ 
            '    <body>'+
            `       <p id = "name">Hello ${firstname}</p>`+
            '    </body>'+
            '</html>');
...
```

Comment: Thank you pesehr! But it displays Hello ${firstname} on the page :(