# How do I import a JavaScript variable that is in a node.js project to a html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, import, export

I want to know how do I import variables from a node project into a normal javascript file that doesn't use node. I only need the value of the variables

my index.js file:

```js
const sequelize = require('sequelize')

const bd =  new sequelize('usuarios', 'root', 'sintese>marketing', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
})

const Usuario = bd.define('usuario', {
    telefone: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    ddd: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    data_de_entrada: {
        type: sequelize.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false
    }
})

async function contar_entrantes(dia, mes, ano) {
    dados = await Usuario.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            data_de_entrada: ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia
        }
    })
    return(dados.count)
}
let hoje = new Date();
let entrantes_dia_1 = contar_entrantes(hoje.getDate() - 4, hoje.getMonth() + 1, hoje.getFullYear())
let entrantes_dia_2 = contar_entrantes(hoje.getDate() - 3, hoje.getMonth() + 1, hoje.getFullYear())
let entrantes_dia_3 = contar_entrantes(hoje.getDate() - 2, hoje.getMonth() + 1, hoje.getFullYear())
let entrantes_dia_4 = contar_entrantes(hoje.getDate() - 1, hoje.getMonth() + 1, hoje.getFullYear())
let entrantes_dia_5 = contar_entrantes(hoje.getDate() - 4, hoje.getMonth() + 1, hoje.getFullYear())

let dia_1 = (hoje.getDate() - 4) + '/' + (hoje.getMonth()+1) + '/' + hoje.getFullYear()
let dia_2 = (hoje.getDate() - 3) + '/' + (hoje.getMonth()+1) + '/' + hoje.getFullYear()
let dia_3 = (hoje.getDate() - 2) + '/' + (hoje.getMonth()+1) + '/' + hoje.getFullYear()
let dia_4 = (hoje.getDate() - 1) + '/' + (hoje.getMonth()+1) + '/' + hoje.getFullYear()
let dia_5 = hoje.getDate() + '/' + (hoje.getMonth()+1) + '/' + hoje.getFullYear()

module.exports = {entrantes_dia_1, entrantes_dia_2, entrantes_dia_3, entrantes_dia_4, entrantes_dia_5, dia_1, dia_2, dia_3, dia_4, dia_5}
```

index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <script>
                let ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

                let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: [dia_1, dia_2, dia_3, dia_4, dia_5],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Entrantes',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                            data: [entrantes_dia_1,
                                entrantes_dia_2,
                                entrantes_dia_3,
                                entrantes_dia_4,
                                entrantes_dia_5]
                        }]
                    }
                })
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to use the variables in module export in my html file. I only need these variables values. It says these variables aren't defined when I try to use them in html script. How do I do this?

Comment: Jeez.  That changes it to a whole different kind of question and your approach is pretty far off.  Now it appears you want to INJECT some data that you get from a database on the server into a JS file that the browser can then use.  I will delete my answer as it was answering a different question from what you first asked.  No more time tonight to devote to a completely different question.  Hopefully someone else will come along to help.

Comment: Using express? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html