# Passing data by using express Router

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a node.js project where I need to pass data from js file to html file

**js file code**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const path = require('path');

const db = require('Dal/ProductsDal');

const productsArray = db.showAll();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/home.html') , {obj: productsArray })
})

module.exports = router;
```

**html file code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Node.Js Concluding Exercise</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div>
        products
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I show the product array in html div?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a variable from node.js to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html)

Comment: No, but thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Using template engines with Express

A template engine enables you to use static template files in your application. At runtime, the template engine replaces variables in a template file with actual values and transforms the template into an HTML file sent to the client. This approach makes it easier to design an HTML page.

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0):

You could read the html file from node with a file reader and look for the div tag and replace with the data.

example code below

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        const products = 'some data';
        const result = data.toString('utf8').replace('<div>products</div>', products);
        res.write(result);
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thats maybe okay for small files or lets say one line, but if this get larger with more variables? ...

Comment: I would go for a template engine of node (pug, ejs, handlebars).